# Finding value from a third column based on specific row criteria of 2 other columns

Tags: sql

**EDITED ON March 6, 2023.** Added more information. Also providing the solution based on feedback from people on this thread. Thanks!!

In the example provided below, based on conditions that will filter out rows on two columns, I want to filter them out again to get the CacheUID (third column)

The code below will allow you to recreate the following resultset:

| CacheUID | FilterCriteriaName | CriteriaValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | 4 |
| 2 | Product | 4 |
| 2 | Product | 6 |
| 3 | Product | 4 |
| 3 | Product | 6 |
| 3 | Product | 8 |
| 4 | Equipment | 16 |
| 4 | Equipment | 3 |
| 5 | Equipment | 4 |
| 5 | Equipment | 6 |
| 5 | Product | 6 |
| 5 | Product | 4 |

Based on different combination of rows (per FilterCriteriaName and CriteriaValue), I need to retrieve what is the corresponding CacheUID. The FilterCriteriaName and CriteriaValue corresponds to filter information. Here are two examples:

**Scenario 1:**
Want to retrieve the correct CacheUID (and only 1) when filter is based on Product 4 AND Product 6.The combination of Product 4 and 6 can be found in CacheUID 2, 3 and 5. But ONLY CacheUID 2 contains ONLY these criteria.

**Scenario 2:**
Want to retrieve the correct CacheUID (and only 1) when filter is based on Product 4 AND Product 6 AND Equipment 6.Product 4 can be found in CacheUID 1, 2, 3 and 5. Product 6 can be found in CacheUID 2, 3, 4 and 5. Equipment 6 can be found in CacheUID 5, But, the combination of Product 4 and 6 and Equipment 6 can be found only in CacheUID 5.

And here are the result I need for each scenario

**Scenario 1:**

| CacheUID |
| --- |
| 2 |

**Scenario 2:**

| CacheUID |
| --- |
| 5 |

Run the query below that will create the right data to cover the scenarios listed and now contains the solution in the last two SELECT.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
    CacheUID [bigint] NOT NULL,
    FilterCriteriaName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CriteriaValue [bigint] NOT NULL,
    UID [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 1, 4)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 2, 4)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 2, 6)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 3, 4)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 3, 6)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 3, 8)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Equipment', 4, 16)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Equipment', 4, 3)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Equipment', 5, 4)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Equipment', 5, 6)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 5, 6)

INSERT  #TestTable (FilterCriteriaName, CacheUID, CriteriaValue)
VALUES  ('Product', 5, 4)

SELECT  CacheUID, FilterCriteriaName, CriteriaValue
FROM    #TestTable

-----------------------------------------------
-- Scenario 1: Filter on two products (4, 6) --
-----------------------------------------------

SELECT      'Scenario 1 - Only 4 or 6', CacheUID
FROM        #TestTable
GROUP BY    CacheUID
HAVING      COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Product' AND CriteriaValue = 4 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND            -- Product 4 present
            COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Product' AND CriteriaValue = 6 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND            -- Prodct 6 present
            COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Product' AND CriteriaValue NOT IN (4, 6) THEN 1 END) = 0 AND  -- Only product 4 or 6
            COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Equipment' AND CriteriaValue > 0 THEN 0 END) = 0

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scenario 2: Filter on two products (4, 6) and one equipment (6) --
---------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT      'Scenario 2 - Only Product 4, 6 Present + Equipment 6', CacheUID
FROM        #TestTable
GROUP BY    CacheUID
HAVING      COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Product' AND CriteriaValue = 4 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND            -- Product 4 present
            COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Product' AND CriteriaValue = 6 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND            -- Product 6 present
            COUNT(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Product' AND CriteriaValue NOT IN (4, 6) THEN 1 END) = 0 AND  -- Only Product 4 or 6
            Count(CASE WHEN FilterCriteriaName = 'Equipment' AND CriteriaValue = 6 THEN 1 END) = 1              -- Equipment 6 present


DROP TABLE #TestTable
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact output you expect here?

Comment: The query should only return 2, which is the only CacheUID that corresponds to the combinations Product-4 and Product-6, and nothing more. My query returns more now, as my two criteria are also found in CacheUID 3.

Comment: your expected result table includes 2 and 3, but you say you want to exclude 3

Comment: i am not sure if using group_concat could be good specially in performance matter like follwoing SELECT      CacheUID 
FROM        testtable
where FilterCriteriaName = 'Product'
GROUP BY    CacheUID
having group_concat(CriteriaValue) = "4,6"

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I clarified scenarios based on your questions. I also added the solution in my code for people that will look at this post later on. Thanks for the feedback. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost correct, and can be made to work by adding a third assertion in the `HAVING` clause which excludes any criteria value which is *not* 4 or 6:

```sql
SELECT CacheUID
FROM #TestTable
WHERE FilterCriteriaName = 'Product'
GROUP BY CacheUID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN CriteriaValue = 4 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND         -- 4 present
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CriteriaValue = 6 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND         -- 6 present
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CriteriaValue NOT IN (4, 6) THEN 1 END) = 0;  -- only 4 or 6
```